# How can two 100% identical files have different sizes?

Tags: macos, file, unix, size, hexdump

I have two **100% identical** empty `.sh` shell script files on Mac:

- encrypt.sh: **299 bytes**
- decrypt.sh: **13 bytes** (Actually this size is correct, since I have 13 bytes: 11 character + two new line)

The contents of `encrypt.sh` and its hexdump:
[image: encrypt.sh]

The contents of `decrypt.sh` and its hexdump:
[image: decrypt.sh]

The file info window of `encrypt.sh`:

[image: encrypt info]

The file info window of `decrypt.sh`:

[image: decrypt info]

They have the exact same hexdump, then how is it possible that they have different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X file system is implementing forks, so the larger one is likely having something specific stored in its [resource fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork).

Use `ls -l@` to get more details.